# How to get rid of Delete `··` (prettier/prettier) errors in a Vue JS project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, eslintrc

I am trying to get rid of the error in relation to `@vue/prettier`. I have tried a few things, but it seems to throw up even more errors.

My `.eslintrc.js` is as follows:

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true
  },
  extends: ["plugin:vue/essential", "@vue/prettier"],
  rules: {
    "no-console": process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "error" : "off",
    "no-debugger": process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "error" : "off",
  },
  parserOptions: {
    parser: "babel-eslint"
  }
};
```

I tried `"endOfLine":"auto"` within the rules part but this then cause more and also `'prettier/prettier': ['error', {endOfLine: 'auto'}]`

I have removed tabbed spacing from the bewlow;

```
    events_filtered_monthsNews: function() {
        return this.news.filter(u => u.monthsNews)
    },
```

To be formatted like this;

```
        events_filtered_monthsNews: function() {return this.news.filter(u => u.monthsNews)},
```

Which removes warnings but now creates even more errors and is totally impractical for working.

Comment: npm run lint --fix

Answer (score 21):

#### `endOfLine`

If you don't care about line endings, set `endOfLine` to `off`:

```js
// .eslintrc.js
module.exports = {
  rules: {
    "prettier/prettier": ["error", { endOfLine: "off" }],
  },
};
```

#### `tabWidth`

Your current text is using 4-space tabs, but Prettier by default expects 2-space tabs.

So this input:

```js
    events_filtered_monthsNews: function() {
        return this.news.filter(u => u.monthsNews)
    },
```

should be this:

```js
  events_filtered_monthsNews: function() {
    return this.news.filter(u => u.monthsNews)
  },
```

If you prefer 4-space tabs, configure Prettier's [`tabWidth`](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#tab-width) to `4`:

```js
// .eslintrc.js
module.exports = {
  rules: {
    "prettier/prettier": ["error", { tabWidth: 4 }],
  },
};
```

Answer (score 5):

I got Some error, "error  Delete `␍`  prettier/prettier" in multiple lines on my code, then I resolved this issue by follow these steps below:

Open Your project:

> cd "project folder"

This command can fix all errors

> npm run lint --fix

Then:

> npm run lint

Initially reports errors, but should be fixed once nuxt/create-nuxt-app#100 is released.

Answer (score 5):

If you get an error for endOfLine: "off", following worked for me:

```
rules: { "prettier/prettier": ["error", { endOfLine: "auto" }] }
```

Answer (score 3):

**If you want to disable (prettier/prettier) use this code. In the .eslintrc.json file**

rules: {
'prettier/prettier': 'off'
},

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using visual studio code, it could be that vs code is automatically adding the carriage return for you. You can disable this by by clicking on CRLF in the blue bar in the bottom right of your screen. Setting it to LF fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solutions given none worked for me but I could what worked

```
"prettier/prettier": 0,
```

by setting prettier to 0, in the .eslintrc file, the error messages stopped showing.

if your .eslintrc does not have the rules map, you can easily write it

```
rules: {
   "prettier/prettier": 0,
}
```